# How do you rephrase "mettre longtemps" into "prendre longtemps"?

Tags: usage, verbes

When saying "it will take (for example, three hours) to do it", I learned that French uses "mettre" or "prendre".

> - Ils ne **mettront** pas **longtemps** à s’apercevoir qu'elle est disparue.

How do you rephrase this sentence by using "prendre" instead? Is it always possible to change "mettre" into "prendre" when talking about how much time required?

Comment: We mostly use "avoir disparu" rather than "être disparu" (more formal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est quasiment la même chose, mais il y a des formes qui sonnent plus correctes que d'autres, selon le contexte grammatical.

Je n'ai pas fait de recherche pour trouver des règles (j'enrichirai peut-être ma réponse plus tard, si je trouve), ainsi, ce qui suit est complètement empirique, mais ça fonctionne.

-- **Pour des personnes**:
Avec **mettre**.

- Ils ne *mettront* pas longtemps.
- Ils ne *mettront* pas longtemps à arriver.
- Ils ne *mettront* pas longtemps à se faire virer.

--**Pour des personnes**: Avec **prendre**

Le seul usage vraiment correct, de "ne prendre pas longtemps" avec des personnes, que j'ai pu trouver, c'est quand les personnes font une action.

- Ils ne prendront pas longtemps *pour* se préparer.

(On pourrait aussi dire ici: *Ils ne mettront pas longtemps pour se préparer*)

Ici ils font l'action. Ils ne prendront pas longtemps (= ne prendront pas beaucoup de temps) pour faire ceci ou cela.

S'ils ne font pas l'action, Ils ne *mettront* pas beaucoup de temps à se faire virer par leur patron. (le patron fait l'action). Les jours sont comptés, le temps dont ils disposent est compté.

-- **Avec l'impersonnel** "ça", qui désigne généralement un événement, un chose, un sentiment, peu importe, toute chose inanimée:

Avec **mettre**:

- ça ne *prendra* pas bien longtemps.
- ça ne *prendra* pas longtemps.

Avec **prendre**:

Mais quand il y a précision, il vaut mieux utiliser le verbe "mettre":

- ça ne *mettra* pas longtemps ***à arriver***.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost always possible to switch to the second phrasing.  In fact, in my area, we rarely use the phraseology associated with "mettre" (though it would certainly be valid); we usually use "prendre."  In the example you gave, we would say,

> Ça ne prendra pas longtemps pour qu'ils s’aperçoivent qu'elle est disparue.

or (per comments)

> Ça ne leur prendra pas longtemps pour s’aperçoivent qu'elle est disparue.

Comment: Or *"Ça ne leur prendra pas longtemps pour s'apercevoir qu'elle est disparue."* Maybe even *"Ils ne prendront pas longtemps à s'apercevoir qu'elle est disparue."*?

Comment: That's true; that might even be a better rendition, eh?

Comment: Not sure about my second proposition indeed, it may be a mistake, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, come to think of it, it could give the nuance of "They won't take long figuring out..." instead of "It won't take long for them to figure out," implying that there is a process to figuring out that she is missing which will take time, albeit not much.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Hi. It seems to me that "*mettre*" takes a person [Je/Tu/Elle] as the subject, while "*prendre*" needs an impersonal subject [Ça/Cela/etc]. So I'm curious about the construction of your 2nd example.

Comment: @Ahalone-zee If you have some sources that explicitely say that, so it may be true. But as a French guy, I often hear or say *je prends longtemps*, *je mets longtemps*, *ça prend longtemps*, *ça met longtemps*. It doesn't mean it's correct of course, I wouldn't be surprised if there is a rule for these cases.

Comment: @Simon,  http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/je+prends+le+temps.html

Comment: Firstly it's another case (*prendre le temps*), secondly it's a very bad source, only examples from all over the web, I often find mistakes on Linguee.

Answer (score 0):

The adequate form depends on the subject.

> **Quelqu'un** *met* du temps à faire quelque chose
>
> **Cela** *prend* du temps (à quelqu'un) de faire quelque chose

See http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/prendre

> B. − [Le suj. désigne un procès; la relation concerne sa durée] Consommer du temps, demander une certaine durée pour être réalisé,
>   mené à bien

http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mettre

> 5. a) [Le compl. dir. désigne ou spécifie une durée] Mettre qqc. à/pour + inf